# Mongo: Could number of index greater than number of document?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

As I understand, each document in collection have a document index, except case sparse index.

I have `users` collection and created an index for it, when I use aggregate to get data from `posts` collection and use a stage with `$lookup` operation to get data from `users` collection. The response time from mongo server is very slow, and I tried to explain('executionStats') the query, I see at stage `$lookup` from `users` collection, indexesUsed is correct, but `totalDocExamined` is greater than 16.000.000 while the `users` collection have only 300.000 document.

It's a mongo problem or mine ? Should I try reIndex `users` collection ?

Comment: Please provide a link to that explain output, otherwise we are just guessing. Your comment about "_each document in collection have a document index_" is incorrect or at least poorly worded. Similarly using a reindex command is unlikely to fix anything, but the explain output should help confirm what the problem is and what we can do to resolve it

Comment: MongoDB can have more index keys than documents for the related collection if the field that is indexed is an array.  This is referred to as a multi-key index.

Comment: By the way, using MongoDB as a relational database via $lookup misses the *huge* performance benefits associated with embedding related data into the parent document (so no lookup is required).

Comment: @user20042973 I can't public information, because it's a production issue, any thanks for read my question, as I said, I tried drop and reCreated index for `users` collection and it's worked. Response time reduce 10 times. `totalDocumentExamined` is reduce to 5,000.

Comment: @barrypicker it's not an array, it's just a String or Number, but I resolved my issue by reIndex. Anyway, thanks for your information about $lookup performance.

Comment: Closed this post